# Access's trim() function not recognized on another machine

Tags: ms-access, vba

I built a modest Access DB and asked a coworker to test it on her machine.  To my surprise, an error message popped up, saying it didn't recognize Trim(). The query in question is a standard select query that pulls from a MSSQL Server DB. Why isn't it recognized on her machine and how do I get around this?

(We both use MS Office 2003 and have network permissions to the same source tables.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me guess, you are using Trim with a linked table and it works on your PC but not your colleague's? If so, check the references in the code window for any marked MISSING. Missing references lead to quite odd errors.

Comment: Didn't think that would be a problem since I'm not using any VBA at all, but I did remove a couple of references anyway and it worked.