# UCase not being recognised in VBE, what reference is needed?

Tags: excel, vba

I am going through some vba code and I get a compile error on UCase(). It says compile error: can't find project or library. I have never encountered this before, what library do I need to add through references to recognise this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [vba code works in 2010 ad doesn't work in 2007](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110398/vba-code-works-in-2010-ad-doesnt-work-in-2007)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/11449858/11683.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the References dialog and you should find at least one reference marked "MISSING:" Remove that missing reference and all should be well.

Missing references can cause VBA to act strangely including not recognising built-in keywords

Comment: As an example, this happened when we (as the developers) had the Rubberduck add-in added as a reference, but the user didn't have it installed. Before deploying we need to remove this reference to avoid the user having the `MISSING: Rubberduck AddIn #Rubberduck AddIn` reference. Adding the example as I didn't understand what was meant by this answer when I first read it a few weeks back.

Answer (score 2):

I've also faced this same problem. But a kind of trick resolved the error:

Just replace `lcase` or `ucase` with `vba.lcase` or `vba.ucase` respectively.