Access.DoCmd.OpenReport throws, "Undefined function 'Trim' in expression." when running with 64 bit Access
System works well with 32 bit Access, but we're moving to Windows 11, etc.
I resolved a Declare issue in VBA using PtrSafe as described.  That seems to have worked.
Now when calling Access.DoCmd.OpenReport() against 64 bit Access, it throws an exception with message, "Undefined function 'Trim' in expression."
Code is simiar to this:
Try
    Dim tmpAccess As Access.Application = OpenAccessDatabase(reportTemplatesPath)
    tmpAccess.Visible = True
    Dim whereClause As String = "userid = '" & Environment.UserName & "'"

    tmpAccess.DoCmd.OpenReport(inReportName, Access.AcView.acViewPreview, , whereClause, Access.AcWindowMode.acWindowNormal)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message)
End Try

I'm new to VB and VBA.  I haven't tried too much as I'm not sure how to resolve this.  It, in my mind, is obviously a 32 vs. 64 bit issue as it works just fine with 32 bit Access.
I've searched online for this issue. But, adding 'Trim' to the search never results in anything relevant.  I also have not found anything about OpenReport() regarding 32 vs 64 bit.

Similar problem: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/trim-error-help.188879/   Some suggestions there.   At a guess I'd say there's a missing/broken reference in your Access database.  Sometimes the error message points to something other than the root cause - I've seen it complain about other VBA string functions such as Left(), Right() etc.

Most likely missing reference- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610934/accesss-trim-function-not-recognized-on-another-machine

And that is exactly what we found.  Surprised me that it was a reference based on the error message.  There was a reference that was listed as "MISSING: MaybryBarcode" in the list.  I had not looked at references prior and quite honestly didn't know where to find them, I got help from a coworker.  We got that re-installed and things are working as they should.  Thank you for your responses.  Calling this solved.
